# "Method undefined for type" error, works with upcast - what is going on?

Tags: java, inheritance

This has me stumped :) The code is working so it is more of a mental challenge. I am trying to style an individual tab on a GWT TabBar. The setup of this widget is a tad peculiar - the Tab class is defined as an inner interface inside the TabBar class and it is implemented by an inner class also in TabBar called ClickDelegatePanel. The full code of TabBar is here

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.java

The key bits (I think!) are the interface..

```
public interface Tab extends HasAllKeyHandlers, HasClickHandlers, HasWordWrap {
```

and the implementation...

```
private class ClickDelegatePanel extends Composite implements Tab {
```

The method to add a style is **addStyleName** which is offered by UIObject, a parent of Composite. If I get a particular Tab from my TabBar and try to use this method, I get an error in Eclipse (and a compilation error). Code is like this...

```
Tab myTab = tabPanel.getTabBar().getTab(3);
myTab.addStyleName("gwt-TabBarItem-selected");
```

But if I upcast to UIObject, it works...

```
UIObject myTab = (UIObject) tabPanel.getTabBar().getTab(3);
myTab.addStyleName("gwt-TabBarItem-selected");
```

Eclipse even recognises this and offers a Quick Fix suggestion that does a more temporary upcast...

```
Tab myTab = tabPanel.getTabBar().getTab(3);
((UIObject) myTab).addStyleName("gwt-TabBarItem-selected");
```

I've had a good old Google and can't figure out what is going on. It shouldn't be possible to completely hide a superclass method, right? Any discussion on upcasting seems to say its main use is to choose a superclass version of an overloaded method - but addStyleName isn't overloaded. I can only assume it has something to do with the way Tab is being defined, as an inner interface implemented by an inner class which extends the superclass I'm after. So, what is happening here? Why is using the interface type stopping me accessing superclass methods from the implementing class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Composite` extends `UIObject`, **not** `Tab`. Your reference is to a `Tab` object, not a `ClickDelegatePanel` (which is a `Composite`, and thus a `UIObject`). The Tab interface does not declare addStyleName, which is what Eclipse is telling you. You **happen** to be able to successfully cast Tab to UIObject here, but that is not guaranteed by the type hierarchy -- I could write a class that implements Tab which is not a UIObject. In that case, the cast would fail.

Comment: Actually, in this case you can cast Tab to ClickDelegatePanel as the getTab method returns a ClickDelegatePanel object through Tab interface return type.

Comment: You can, but only because you are 'cheating' and know the concrete implementation of `Tab`. That is my point -- the compiler does not have this sort of type information at hand. Also, you should not rely on it. For a contrived example, imagine `getTab` changes to return a `Proxy` tab that does some sort of lazy loading. The proxy will fail the cast to ClickDelegatePanel.

Comment: I agree, but when I said "in this case", I mean this is a GWT implementation and all the classes are implementation dependent (the TabBar class).

Comment: In fact you can't cast to ClickDelegatePanel, presumably because the implementation is a private inner class. I think if the cast to ClickDelegatePanel had worked I might have felt clearer on it, having to go up the hierarchy from a private implementing class is probably what feels peculiar here.